# Convert a string with multiple values and merge the data with same keys

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the string that am getting by submitting a form.

```
qcl[]=25.17.74&qcl[]=25.20.105&qcr[]=24.01&qcr[]=24.01
```

How do i convert the string to Array so that i get the array in the below format.

```
Array( [qcl] => 25.17.74 [qcl] => 25.20.105 ) and  Array( [qcr] => 24.01 [qcr] => 24.01 )
```

I tried exploding array with & and then exploding by = but i eneded up with this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => qcl[]
            [1] => 25.17.74
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => qcl[]
            [1] => 25.20.105
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => qcr[]
            [1] => 24.01
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => qcr[]
            [1] => 24.02
        )

)
```

Please help me further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str)

```
parse_str("qcl[]=25.17.74&qcl[]=25.20.105&qcr[]=24.01&qcr[]=24.01");
print_r($qcl);
print_r($qcr);
```

Output

```
// QCL
Array (
    [0] => 25.17.74
    [1] => 25.20.105
)

// QCR
Array (
    [0] => 24.01
    [1] => 24.01
)
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rO3FOJ)</kbd>